# How to export an android library in order to make it available from another computer? (Having a "403 forbidden access error")

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using a library for my project that permits to store values by keys and values (https://github.com/netguru/Kissme). However, I cannot use this library anymore from computers that did not use this library yet (it gives me "403 forbidden access" when I try to import the library into the dependencies) which prevents any building of the project.

Thus, here is my question : is there a way to export this library from the prior computer that can still build the project, in order to import it locally from the computer that can not access to the https://github.com/netguru/Kissme server during the importation?

I would like to highlight that this issue does not come from any problem within the .gradle and .idea folders, because I did have delete them and the issue is still occurring after invalidating caches and restarting. The problem is really coming from the fact that the developers did shut down access to the server.

I really hope that one of you can solve this problem because it will take me more of 3 weeks to refactor everything into Room library.

Comment: You could always clone the repo and build it locally.

Comment: Please remove the jetpack compose tag. It doesn't belong to this category